# Промежутки в таблице в мозиле

Tags: html

создаю таблицу хтмл в хроме показывает нормально в мозиле есть промежутки между ячейками, как их устранить? Нужно чтобы три элемента выглядели как одна картинка.

```html
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin-top:0;border-spacing:0;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/polyglot-404.png" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <object width="1000" height="660" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="src" value="trol_oop.swf" />
        <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1000" height="670" src="trol_oop.swf" quality="high" />
      </object>

    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/polyglot-404.png">
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Отформатируй нормально код

Comment: @Qwertiy, готово

Comment: @Grundy, вообще-то я хотел сниппет... Желательно без `object`а. Кстати, ответ, скорее всего, `display:block` или `border-collapse:collapse`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, _отформатируй_ - Ну никак не похоже на _сделай snippet_ :-D

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: ничё не помагает мозилла не признаёт ничего, блииин((

Comment: Заменил картинки на доступные. В FF вижу небольшой промежуток, в Chromium промежуток размером с картинку.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, это потому что там ссылка на несуществующую флэшку

Comment: @VenZell а, точно. Ну тогда неудивительно, что промежуток. Где бы взять флешку для примера?

Answer (score 2):

Попробую угадать.

Вариант 1:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
img, object {
  display: block;
}
```

Вариант 3:

```
img, object {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```